# Issues in capturing Wireshark filters

Tags: wireshark

I am trying to launch wireshark from the cli with the following options...

```
wireshark -k -i eth2 -a filesize:1000000 -f <capture filter>
```

The issue I have is that I want to use a pre-defined wireshark filter... when I run the above with the actual filter in the cli cmd it works, when I use a pre-defined one it fails..

Working example:

```
wireshark -k -i eth2 -a filesize:1000000 -f "host 40.40.41.42"
```

Failure example (the one I am trying to use):

```
wireshark -k -i eth2 -a filesize:1000000 -f pre-defined-capture1
```

Where pre-defined-capture1 filter does show up under "Capture -> Options -> Capture Filter" list...

The error i get is that the filter is not valid, I would like to specify the filter I saved in the capture filters list if thats possible...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select "Capture -> Capture Filters" you will get a window in which you can define, alter and delete capture filters for future use. You can't actually activate a capture filter from there.

One of the reasons is that some capture filters might work on some physical interfaces while they might not work on others. That's why you need to activate a capture filter with the capture options when you start your capture session.

Go to "Capture -> Options" and use the "Capture Filter" button to select your pre-defined capture filter. Or just type the filter you need in the dialog box.

If you're using version 1.7.0 (or higher), you will need to doubleclick on the interface you are going to capture from first, as you can capture on multiple interfaces at once beginning with version 1.7.0 and you can set the capture filter differently for each interface.

[**Please feel free to ask the Wireshark Community if you have got any doubts that you require more clarifications.**](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/ask/)

Comment: @Vinny, hi Yes I do understand that option but I am trying to do this from the command line rather than the GUI... do  you know if there are any options from the command line to use the filter directly?

Comment: @gates - If that is the case, I recommend you to post this query in the wireshark community.